# Calling dictionary keys using another array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` showing data from an `Array` of keys.

```
var pokemonData = ["Nidoran", "Clefairy", "Spearow", "Ivysaur", "Gengar", "Arcanine", "Gyarados", "Onix", "Pikachu", "Vaporeon"]
```

Also I have this `Dictionary`, but i want call each key to it shows in a label whenever i choose something on the picker.

```
var typeData = [

    "Nidoran" : "Type: Poison",
    "Clefairy" : "Type: Normal",
    "Spearow" : "Type: Normal, Flying",
    "Ivysaur" : "Type: Grass, Poison",
    "Gengar" : "Type: Ghost, Poison",
    "Arcanine" : "Type: Fire",
    "Gyarados" : "Type: Water, Flying",
    "Onix" : "Type: Rock, Ground",
    "Pikachu" : "Type: Electric",
    "Vaporeon" : "Type: Water"

]
```

How can I do that? I use this picker function to change the labels

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    pokeLabel.text = pokemonData[row]

}
```

My second label is...

```
@IBOutlet weak var typeLabel: UILabel!
```

Comment: I would suggest an alternative approach: Keep `typeData` around, but define `pokemonData` to be `typeData.key`. This way you only have to write the pokemon in one place, and both will get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use that typeData `Dictionary` to get value for selected key.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
     pokeLabel.text = pokemonData[row]
     typeLabel.text = typeData[pokemonData[row]]
}
```

Comment: @VeronicaG Check latest edit i have just mismatch the label :)

Comment: @VeronicaG if this answers your question, please accept the answer